# Hit CURL after successfully payment in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I want to put my curl code after successful payment in prestashop where can i put my code after putting condition:

```
if(payment == "successful") {
  /* My curl code */
}
```

Comment: use prestashop hooks, there's a hook order confirmation, you can use this hook. This hook is triggered when an order placed successfully and confirmed.

Comment: Hi I confuse little bit, as you said that i use order-confirmation.tpl file.I found this file but where i put my condition if customer done payment successfully then curl request sent orderwise no curl request gone.

Comment: im not saying about order-confirmation.tpl, im discusing about hooks, create a module and register orderconfirmation hook, and place your curl request inside ordreconfirmation hook function

Comment: Ok, But i have question why i need to create module i want only that function where it checks payment done successfully or not if done successfully then send curl request otherwise showing error.

Comment: go to all payment modules file and there will be the same hook order confirmation in the module's main php file, write your code there

Comment: I found orderConfirmation hook in my hook.php file which is in inside presta_folder/classes/Hook.php but its deprecated and after i search this hook changed with displayOrderConfirmation hook and it is in presta_folder/controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php please review and tell me is it write place to put my CURL code.